# Ambiguity Errors with operator<< Overloads in custom std::ostream Subclass

Tags: c++, stl

While trying to develop a class inheriting from both `std::stringbuf` and `std::ostream` and giving it a custom `operator<<()` overload (which should work for this class, but not for `std::ostream` in general), I got some ambiguity errors I don't understand.

The problems are in the bottom half of the following code. If I remove the `operator<<()` overload, I do not get any errors (`g++ --std=c++17 -o foo.exe foo.cpp` using g++ 9.2.0, MSYS2 build on Windows).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>

class MyStream:
    private std::stringbuf,
    public std::ostream
{
public:
    MyStream() noexcept:
        std::stringbuf(),
        std::ostream(this)
    {}

    ~MyStream()
    {
        if (pptr() - pbase() < 2)
        { sync(); }
    }

protected:
    virtual int sync() override
    {
        // make sure there actually is something to sync
        if (pptr() - pbase() < 2)
        { return 0; }

        const std::string message{str()};
        const std::size_t length{message.length()};

        // update the pointers for the next sync
        setp(pbase() + length, epptr());

        std::cout << message;

        return std::stringbuf::sync();
    }
};

MyStream& operator<<(MyStream& out, bool boolean) noexcept
{ return out << (boolean ? "yes" : "no"); }
/*           ↑
    more than one operator "<<" matches these operands:
        -- function template "std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>
            &std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits> &_Ostr, const char *_Val)"
        -- function template "std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>
            &std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits> &_Ostr, const char *_Val)"
        -- function template "std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>
            &std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits> &_Ostr, const _Elem *_Val)"
        -- function "operator<<(MyStream &out, bool boolean) noexcept"
        -- operand types are: MyStream << const char *
*/

int main()
{
    MyStream stream;

    stream << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    /*     ↑
        more than one operator "<<" matches these operands:
            -- function template "std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>
                &std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits> &_Ostr, const char *_Val)"
            -- function template "std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits>
                &std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, _Traits> &_Ostr, const char *_Val)"
            -- function template "std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>
                &std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits> &_Ostr, const _Elem *_Val)"
            -- function "operator<<(MyStream &out, bool boolean) noexcept"
            -- operand types are: MyStream << const char [12]
    */
}
```

Why is my overload for `bool` a valid candidate for a `char*` argument? How can I do this properly?

Comment: Why derive from both `ostream` and `streambuf`?  A stream and a stream buffer are different things.

Comment: So I can pass `this` as underlying stream buffer to the `ostream` constructor without the need of additional classes. In my actual use case I need to override the `sync` method of `stringbuf` in a more reasonable way than in this example. Eventually I want an object one can use like `cout` (thus `ostream` as base) with special treatment for some inputs (in this example `bool`) and I want to do stuff with the resulting string in `sync`.

Comment: Hmm ...  That probably won't work out well.  I don't think it is intended that you put both the stream and its buffer in the same object.  It's probably better to stick to the convention and just create a buffer class.  You don't have to invent another `ostream` - it supports custom buffers i think.

Comment: But how would I add my own extensions then? I don't want every `ostream` to handle `bool` like my class in the example, but only specific instances.

Comment: So you are mixing two things: a customized stream buffer, and a customized   stream. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. Basically, I could also go with the [base from member idiom](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/utility/base_from_member.html) to stash away the `stringbuf` functionality in a member, but I don't think multiple inheritance is the problem here. The base classes do not seem to interfere.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.onlinegdb.com/Hy--sUsKr) seems to work for me under **linux** (g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0) :

```
MyStream& operator<<(MyStream& out, bool boolean)
{
    out << (boolean ? "yes" : "no");
    return out;
}
```

I only changed the return call. That's because `out << (boolean ? "yes" : "no")` will use the base `ostream operator<<` for `char*` types and hence returns a `std::basic_ostream<char>` type rather than a `MyStream` return value type.

And then in `main()` using a `bool`type with a `MyStream operator<<`  works:

```
int main()
{
    MyStream stream;
    bool b=true;

    stream << b << "Hello World" << b << std::endl;  

    //by contrast, this should output "yesHello Worldyes"
    //stream << b << "Hello World";
    //stream << b << std::endl;

    //and so would this kind of ugliness! lol
    //static_cast<MyStream&>(stream << b << "Hello World") << b << std::endl;
}
```

..but once the base-class `ostream operator<<` is invoked for the `"Hello World"` part of the statement, it of course returns a `std::basic_ostream<char>` type :)

..then after that, because there is no existing `ostream operator<<`  for `bool` types, the `bool b` type will get implicitly promoted to a `int` and so the output is: 

`yesHello World1` !

---

### Windows builds

But you seemed to be getting other errors. So while i do not have MSYS2 to hand, i did try to compile the codes on a WinOS with Visual Studio. In my case, at least, your `main()` fails immediately due to ambiguities raised by the VS STL implementation:

```
int main()
{
    MyStream stream;
    stream << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

No need to cast doubt on your current approach as that has already happened in comments. but just in an attempt to answer your questions; then one way round would be to implement another `operator<<` for `MyStream` that handles `char*` types:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>

class MyStream:
    private std::stringbuf,
    public std::ostream
{
public:
    MyStream() noexcept:
        std::stringbuf(),
        std::ostream(this)
    {}

    ~MyStream()
    {
        if (pptr() - pbase() < 2)
        { sync(); }
    }

protected:
    virtual int sync() override
    {
        // make sure there actually is something to sync
        if (pptr() - pbase() < 2)
        { return 0; }

        const std::string message{str()};
        const std::size_t length{message.length()};

        // update the pointers for the next sync
        setp(pbase() + length, epptr());

        std::cout << message;

        return std::stringbuf::sync();
    }
};

MyStream& operator<<(MyStream& out, const char* str)
{
    static_cast<std::ostream&>(out) << str;
    return out;
}

MyStream& operator<<(MyStream& out, bool boolean) noexcept
{ return out << (boolean ? "yes" : "no"); }


int main()
{
    MyStream stream;
    bool b=1;      
    stream << b << " oook " << b << std::endl;    
}
```

Alternatively, since `MyStream` actually *is* derived from `ostream` then we can make use of any `operator<<` for the `ostream` type with an explicit cast. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <sstream>

class MyStream:
    private std::stringbuf,
    public std::ostream
{
public:
    MyStream() noexcept:
        std::stringbuf(),
        std::ostream(this)
    {}

    ~MyStream()
    {
        if (pptr() - pbase() < 2)
        { sync(); }
    }

protected:
    virtual int sync() override
    {
        // make sure there actually is something to sync
        if (pptr() - pbase() < 2)
        { return 0; }

        const std::string message{str()};
        const std::size_t length{message.length()};

        // update the pointers for the next sync
        setp(pbase() + length, epptr());

        std::cout << message;

        return std::stringbuf::sync();
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(MyStream& out, bool boolean) noexcept
{
    return static_cast<std::ostream&>(out) << (boolean ? "yes" : "no");
}

int main()
{
    MyStream stream;
    bool b=1;

    stream << b << " ooOok ";
    stream << b << std::endl;
}
```

where the output is hopefully:

`yes ooOok yes`

Comment: Thank you for your investigations. I hope it didn't steal too much of your time. Your first fix removes an error indeed. One mistake on my side was that I wrote about errors, when what I meant were just warnings. Bad enough, but the program ran after fixing the return value. I found a solution a bit similar to yours, but more generic. I will post it later here and explain another issue it leaves open.

Comment: hehe, no it's fine. been about a yr since my last SO contribution.. glad to know you have things sorted now =)